# How to access a method of an object passed as argument in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

lets say I have two to packages like this:

```
├── packages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── packageA
│   │   ├── classA.py
│   │   ├── classB.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── packageB
│   │   ├── classC.py
│   │   └── __init__.py       
└── test
   ├── __init__.py
   └── test.py
```

this is the content of the py files:

- `classA.py`:

```py
class classA:
    def __init__(self, a ,b):
        self.__attributeA = a
        self.__attributeB = b

    def getAttributeA(self):
        return self.__attributeA

    def getAttributeB(self):
        return self.__attributeB
```

- `classB.py`:

```py
from packages.packageA import classA

class classB:
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def getList(self):
        list = [classA.classA(10, 11), classA.classA(20, 21)]
        return list
```

- `classC.py`:

```py
class classC:
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def method(self,object):
        for element in object:
            print(element.getAttributeA)
```

- `test.py`:

```py
from packages.packageA import classB
from packages.packageB import classC

testClassB = classB.classB().getList()
for element in testClassB:
    print(element.getAttributeA())

testClassC = classC.classC()
testClassC.method(testClassB)
```

- In the `test.py`, creating two instances one of `classB` and one of `classC`.
- I try to print the values of the Items in the list which are `classA` objects, these values are gotten using the getters.

This works like I expected, but when i try to pass the list to `classC`, and try to do the same, i get this output:

```
    <bound method classA.getAttribteA of <packages.packageA.classA.classA object at 0x7fd038244a20>>
    <bound method classA.getAttribteA of <packages.packageA.classA.classA object at 0x7fd0382448d0>>
```

when i should have gotten this :

```
10
20
```

why is this happening ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in classC you're printing the method itself, and not the result of the method call,

change `classC.py` to this :

```
class classC:
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def method(self,object):
        for element in object:
            print(element.getAttributeA()) ## added ()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print the object itself than the value of it.

```
print(element.getAttributeA)

#Changed to 
print(element.getAttributeA())
```